# How do I actually add specific content (other than blog posts) to a Wordpress blog?

Tags: html, wordpress, content-management-system

This is the part that's really confusing me. I have my website customized, themed et al, but I'm not sure how I actually input the content for say, a Contact Me page. When I select add page, it just seems like it's asking for a blog post style page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of themes have custom post types like Contact Pages installed, but you're right, creating a new page will look like a blog post, that's OK. Try creating one and you'll see how it looks, it might be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The "Pages" in WordPress are like blog posts in all aspects except that they will not be shown in the main loop.

WordPress can classify it's posts in "posts types". The posts that you see in the main loop are by default posts with the type "post", and the "pages" are posts with the type "page". With some coding or plugins you could also add other types, like "receipts", "events", "artists" or whatever you want, but later you should tell WordPress how or where to show them, being it the main loop or some other place.

So, the "Pages" are actually posts that will not be shown in the main page by default, nothing else.